# Loop two different category WP_Query

Tags: loop, twitter-bootstrap

I want to loop two different categories to create a layout of two columns in my custom theme. I'm using this code and bootstrap 4 as front-end framework but I'm unable to use all the 12cols available for bootstrap. During the loop, the elements will stack only one time correctly, can I fix this by nesting the loops?

```
<?php 
$main_news = new WP_Query(
    array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'News',
    'posts_per_page' => 6    
    )
);
    if( $main_news->have_posts() ): 
        while( $main_news->have_posts() ): $main_news->the_post(); 
?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 p-4 mt-3">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
            <h4 class="card-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><?php echo get_the_excerpt( get_the_ID() ); ?></p> 
            <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read', ''); ?></a> 
        </div>
<?php 
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

$side_news = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'category_name' => 'Not important', 
    'posts_per_page' => 6 
    ) 
); 
    if( $side_news->have_posts() ): 
        while( $side_news->have_posts() ): $side_news->the_post();
?>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 card shadow-lg d-none d-md-block mt-3">
            <div class="card-body">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo get_the_title( get_the_ID() ); ?></h4>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo get_the_excerpt( get_the_ID() ); ?></p> 
                <a class="" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php _e('Read', ''); ?></a> 
            </div>
        </div>
<?php 
        endwhile; 
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

what I expect is that the two loops will create a column like in the example above:

```
//
<div class="row m-0">
<div class="col-8">content</div><div class="col-4">other content</div> // these two divs aligned 
<div class="col-8">content</div><div class="col-4">other content</div> // etc...
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** This is the layout I expect. I've nested the two loop to get the categories I need, I've just noticed that the content of the nested loop will be repeated in some point. Any fix?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final outlook is a bit tricky to achieve using traditional way. Lets assume both category has at least 6 post. Now first grab the posts using `get_posts()` not <strike>`WP_Query`</strike>

```
$side_news = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'category-slug-1',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
));

$side_news2 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'category-slug-2',
    'posts_per_page' => 6
));
```

**now that we know we have 6 post each let's merge the result as alternative position.**

```
$c_result = array();
while(!empty($side_news) || !empty($side_news2)) {
    if(!empty($side_news)) {
        $result[] = array_shift($side_news);
    }
    if(!empty($side_news2)) {
        $result[] = array_shift($side_news2);
    }
}
```

**Now we have an array with 12 posts. Let's loop through it and achieve the final layout:**

```
echo '<div class="row m-0">';
$i = 0;
foreach ($c_result as $post) {
    $i++;

    $id = $post->ID;
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $content = $post->post_content;

    if($i%2 == 0):
        echo"<div class='col-8'>$id $title $content</div>";
    else:
        echo"<div class='col-4'>$id $title $content</div>";
    endif;
}
echo '</div>';
```

**`get_posts()` returns post as object with following keys:**

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] =>
    [post_author] =>
    [post_date] => 
    [post_date_gmt] => 
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] =>
    [comment_status] =>
    [ping_status] => 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] =>
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 
    [post_modified_gmt] =>
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 
    [guid] => 
    [menu_order] =>
    [post_type] =>
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] =>
    [filter] =>
)
```

Comment: I've tested your solution but I get the content duplied, the two columns will have the same content displayed.

Comment: you requirement is fuzzy. If you are familiar with php you can easily edit and apply my solution to your case. Properly check what I did inside final loop. You will get the idea of what happening there.

Comment: I see that you're using modulo operator to echo the columns based on the loop index increment. That's fine, but The problem for me is that I get the same content for both columns and I have two separate categories that are needed to display

Comment: did you properly edit my ans where i added category slug in get_posts() ? you have to input slug there.

Comment: Also if same post is related to both categories you will get duplicate. Hope you understand. Make sure posts has unique categories

Comment: yes, I used the slug as reported also in the `get_posts()` documentation. The posts in dev mode are dummy generated by a plugin and are assigned to only one category

Comment: in my example get_posts returning latest 6 posts from both category. If one post belongs to both you will get duplicate. In order to avoid this scenario you can use **`'category__not_in' => array('first-category-slug') `**

Comment: Solved, thanks for the help. I was having trouble using the `WP_Query()` way to achieve the layout. Whit your suggestion I get exactly what I need